# datePicker.calendarsPicker issue with chrome Version 56.0.2924.87

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Due to jQuery date picker (using `$datePicker.calendarsPicker`) the issue with `MM/dd/yyyy` format
([image])

with chrome Version 56.0.2924.87., it was not populating date. I added the `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format which is working.

Now the issue I am running into is, if I use `"yyyy-MM-dd"` on my view then for some reason date picker is coming with Aug 2022 records. I don't know how and why? In the console, I see the expected results with min and max date but somehow UI comes up with different data.

Is that something to do with `$datePicker.calendarsPicker` or something else? Here, `jQuery 1.8.7` is used.

**View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(schedule => schedule.DateString, "Date", new { @for = "requested-fulfillment-date" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(schedule => schedule.DateString, new { id="requested-fulfillment-date", type = "date", @class = "date-picker", min = Model.MinOrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), max = Model.MaxOrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), @readonly="readonly" })
```

**Console Result:**

```
<label for="requested-fulfillment-date">Date</label>
<input class="date-picker hasCalendarsPicker" id="requested-fulfillment-date" max="2017-03-12" min="2017-02-10" name="ScheduleModel.DateString" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="2017-02-10">
```

[image]

**UI Result:**

[image]

I tried following approaches but they didn't work:

**Approach 1:**

```
this.setDatePickerWidget = function(event, data) {
    var $datePicker = $("#requested-fulfillment-date", data.element);
    var min = $datePicker.attr("min");
    var max = $datePicker.attr("max");
    var date = $datePicker.val();

    $datePicker.calendarsPicker({
            showTrigger: '.trigger',
            showAnim: 'fadeIn',
            minDate: min,
            maxDate: max,
            defaultDate: date,
            **dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',** 
            onSelect: function () {
              $.publish('order_date_changed', { date: $("#requested-fulfillment-date").val() });
                $("#checkout").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }).prop('type', 'text');
   };
```

Aproach-2:

```
this.setDatePickerWidget = function(event, data) {
    var $datePicker = $("#requested-fulfillment-date", data.element);
    var min = $datePicker.attr("min");
    var max = $datePicker.attr("max");
    var date = $datePicker.val();

    $datePicker.calendarsPicker({
            showTrigger: '.trigger',
            showAnim: 'fadeIn',
            minDate: min,
            maxDate: max,
            defaultDate: date,
            onSelect: function () {
              $.publish('order_date_changed', { date: $("#requested-fulfillment-date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}).val() });
                $("#checkout").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }).prop('type', 'text');
   };
```

**Note:**
If I change my ***View*** to following then date picker starts working. Only issue is, when I select different date , it shows up as `MM/dd/yyyy` format but after a second or two it reverts back to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(schedule => schedule.DateString, new { id = "requested-fulfillment-date", type = "date", @class = "date-picker", min = Model.MinOrderDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), max = Model.MaxOrderDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: `var $datePicker = $("#requested-fulfillment-date", data.element);` the `data.element` is not needed here, since an id must be unique to the document...

Comment: I could not find any reference to `calendarsPicker` on the [jQuery UI site](http://api.jqueryui.com/?s=calendarsPicker). Are you sure you're not using some other widget library?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html, this library is used. I added the latest version from this site but still running into the same issue. Let me see what was the reason for this widget, if I do not find anything which makes sense, I'll directly use `$datepicker`.

Comment: Might want to edit your question to remove reference to jQuery UI since you're not using jQuery UI...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem solved this way (hope it help's):

```
$('.datapicker').datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: This approach comes with different calendar itself which I do not want.

Comment: Ok but you can send your options inside datepicker() function. But let's try this way: try to set new Date() after datepicker() call.